# service cant be started thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a3fba8)

Tags: java, android, exception, service, gps

Updated 13-10-2014: added togglegps.class

Hello i have a simple proyect with two buttons to start and stop a gps service.

as soon as i click the start button to start the service the aplication shuts down.

i get the following logcat

```
10-12 14:23:18.424: I/Choreographer(1300): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

10-12 14:23:18.504: D/gralloc_goldfish(1300): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

10-12 14:24:07.794: E/Google(1300): Service Created

10-12 14:24:07.834: D/AndroidRuntime(1300): Shutting down VM

10-12 14:24:07.864: W/dalvikvm(1300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a3fba8)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300): Process: com.example.newtrack, PID: 1300

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.newtrack.AndroidLocationServices@b2d1b4e8 with Intent { cmp=com.example.newtrack/.AndroidLocationServices }: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=1300, uid=10052

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2719)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=1300, uid=10052

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at com.example.newtrack.ToggleGPS.turnGPSOn(ToggleGPS.java:53)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at com.example.newtrack.AndroidLocationServices.onStart(AndroidLocationServices.java:58)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2702)

10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     ... 10 more
10-12 14:24:11.544: I/Process(1300): Sending signal. PID: 1300 SIG: 9
```

what can be the causes that i can not start the service?
what can i add to the mainactivity?

the manifest has all the permissions and the services are registered

the following is my mainactivity

```
package com.example.newtrack;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //start the service
    public void onClickStartServie(View V)
    {
        //start the service from here //MyService is your service class name
        startService(new Intent(this, AndroidLocationServices.class));
    }
    //Stop the started service
    public void onClickStopService(View V)
    {
        //Stop the running service from here//MyService is your service class name
        //Service will only stop if it is already running.
        stopService(new Intent(this, AndroidLocationServices.class));
    }


}
```

as stated above it has only two onclicks for start and stop service

the main service that is called is the following

```
package com.example.newtrack;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidLocationServices extends Service {

    WakeLock wakeLock;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public AndroidLocationServices() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);

        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotSleep");

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.e("Google", "Service Created");

    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        new ToggleGPS(getApplicationContext()).turnGPSOn();

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Google", "Service Started");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                5000, 5, listener);

    }

    private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.e("Google", "Location Changed");

            if (location == null)
                return;

            if (isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                    jsonObject.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                    jsonObject.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());

                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                    Log.e("request", jsonArray.toString());

                    new LocationWebService().execute(new String[] {
                            Constants.TRACK_URL, jsonArray.toString() });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        new ToggleGPS(getApplicationContext()).turnGPSOff();
        wakeLock.release();

    }

    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

i also post my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newtrack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

       <!-- Permissions to record locations -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newtrack.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service    android:name="com.example.newtrack.AndroidLocationServices" />

        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the class i use to turn on gps is the following

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings;

/**
 * 
 * @author Atish Agrawal
 * 
 */
public class ToggleGPS {

    Context context;

    public ToggleGPS(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean canToggleGPS() {
        PackageManager pacman = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pacInfo = null;

        try {
            pacInfo = pacman.getPackageInfo("com.android.settings",
                    PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false; // package not found
        }

        if (pacInfo != null) {
            for (ActivityInfo actInfo : pacInfo.receivers) {
                // test if recevier is exported. if so, we can toggle GPS.
                if (actInfo.name
                        .equals("com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider")
                        && actInfo.exported) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false; // default
    }

    public void turnGPSOn() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        this.context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
            // if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            this.context.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

    public void turnGPSOff() {
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            this.context.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

}
```

if possible please indicate what i should change - following comments made by @neo

any comments are apreciated

thank you very much.

Comment: Is this happening on android 4.4?

Comment: The API used to compile is 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that the exception line below in the trace:

```
10-12 14:24:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1300):     at com.example.newtrack.ToggleGPS.turnGPSOn(ToggleGPS.java:53)
```

This was a bug before that let you enable the settings by sending the broadcast(that is fixed now). So you will need to ask the User to manually enable the GPS settings using the Intent given below.

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will post the togglegps.class in an update if possible please state what should i substitute